# Background-image of a div won't resize correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm having the issue with website i'm currently working on, background image is not resizing for all mobile and tablet devices.

[Here is website](http://plaforma.me/copy-copy-testtest/)

First image after the slider won't resize correctly even if i done everything i should do. I set it as cover so it can stretch properly but even after that i have problems. I have tried with different resolutions of the picture and finally made it to be div background since i'm using WP i had to do it as raw-html option.

In css it looks like this:

```css
.vc_row.divbgImg.row-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/GlIGTxV.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_row divbgImg row-container"></div>
```

Comment: you'll have to be more specific here. please provide your relevant html and css in a minimal and complete example, and define "i have problems"

Comment: It is wordpress and a theme so I think it would be better to inspect. Because i will make much mess with all that html/css. Is it better now?

Comment: Code seems to be working as expected, what's the issue?

Comment: @APAD1 Background-image after browsers resizes to lower resolutions stretches and loses it's position

Comment: Just tried it now, it holds it's place but lot of white space is created under and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add css:

```
background-position: center;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Also make sure the actual image file has dimensions close to how it will display on the site for best results.

```css
.vc_row.divbgImg.row-container {
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_row divbgImg row-container"></div>
```

Comment: Even after i add 'background-position:center;' it stretches when browser is resizing. Can't seem to hold it's place

Comment: Dude what do you expect when you are trying to make a 258 x 159 image into a full screen width image? It's gonna look blurry. Get a large image

Comment: I don't know where you saw those dimensions.

Comment: I just inspect the class on your website, went through about 5000 divs until I reached the image, hover over url and it shows you the natural dimensions. I see you have made them larger :)

Comment: Those divs are inserted into the theme :/ not my fault really.

Comment: Seems excessive but for a theme understandable. Looks good. Mark as correct if you'd like